# How To Build Select Fields With CssBoundLiftScreen and Record in Lift?

Tags: scala, lift

I have a record class like this:

```
class Address extends Record[Address] {
  def meta = Address

  object countryCode extends OptionalStringField(this, None) {
    override def name = "Country"

    var c = "" // this isn't doing anything but I set it up just to build the simple SHtml.select
    override def toForm = Full(SHtml.select(List(("usa", "usa"),("ca", "ca")), Empty, c = _ ))
  }
  ...
}

object Address extends Address with MetaRecord[Address] { }
```

and then this form is displayed like this:

```
object FormPage extends CssBoundLiftScreen {
  def formName = "MyForm"

  val record = Address.createRecord

  field(record.countryCode, FieldBinding("addressCountryCode")
}
```

in a template like this:

```
<div class="form">
  <div class="lift:FormPage">
    <div class="fields">
      <fieldset>
        <div id="MyForm_addressCountryCode_field"></div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this the right way to do inputs other than a simple text field using Record/CssBoundLiftScreen?  It doesn't seem like this select would update or create a record properly. How would I have the select show the value of the record field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the scaladaoc for [OptionalStringField](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.3/net/liftweb/record/field/OptionalStringField.html), there are two methods that are provided through the superclass [`SettableValueHolder`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.3/net/liftweb/util/SettableValueHolder.html) and that provide access to the underlying value: `get` and `set`

> **def set (in: Option[MyType]) : Option[MyType]**
>
> Set the value of the field to the given value. Note: Because setting a field can fail (return non-Full), this method will return defaultValueBox if the field could not be set.
>
> **get : Option[MyType]**
>
> get the value

I suspect something like this should work for you:

```
override def toForm = Full(SHtml.select(List(("usa", "usa"),("ca", "ca")), get, v => set(Some(v)) ))
```